# send keys to 'display : block' modal in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am having trouble sending keys using selenium.

What I want to do is, I want to send_keys('samsung')
BUT, since 'style = display' is changing from 'none' to 'block' when I click it, I cannot send keys.

```
<div class="modal-search modal-search-analysis" id="analysisSearchModal" style="display: none; transform: translate(0px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
```

after click

```
<div class="modal-search modal-search-analysis" id="analysisSearchModal" style="display: block; transform: translate(0px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
```

**Here are the element**

this webpage's modal is not in iframe, it's in div.

```
<div class="modal-search modal-search-analysis" id="analysisSearchModal" style="display: block; transform: translate(0px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
<div class="modal-search-analysis-keyword" data-tooltip-container="">
<input type="text" name="searchKeywordf714s6nggsw" id="searchKeywordf714s6nggsw" data-index="f714s6nggsw" class="input-style type1 x-small modal-search-analysis-keyword-input search-input input-text" placeholder="Type search keyword" maxlength="15" tabindex="1">
```

**Here are codes that I've been trying**

```
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vbtn btn-submit").click()    #click search button
time.sleep(3)
input = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="searchKeywordn7ssjvuykn"]')
input.send_keys('samsung')
```

**I've also tried this code**

```
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "vbtn btn-submit").click()
time.sleep(3)

container = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="analysisSearchModal"]')
browser.execute_script("argments[0].style.display = 'block';", container)

input = browser.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value = '//*[@id="searchKeywordn7ssjvuykn"]')
input.send_keys('samsung')
```

Thank you for those who can help me solve this problem:)

Answer (score 0):

I can see in your html page id = "searchKeywordf714s6nggsw"
but you are using  id="searchKeywordn7ssjvuykn"

Comment: Hi. Xpath is changing everytime I open the page. So, I tried find_element with class name(this did not changed). But still doesn't work.

Comment: browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "input-keyword-text").click()
time.sleep(10)
browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "input-style type1 x-small modal-search-analysis-keyword-input search-input input-text").send_keys('samsung')

Comment: I think after i type      browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "input-keyword-text").click()      I have to     write some code to change display = 'none' to 'block'      an then type         browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "input-style type1 x-small modal-search-analysis-keyword-input search-input input-text").send_keys('samsung')

Comment: Could you help me with this part?? Thank you :)

Comment: Use this xpath //input[@name="searchKeywordf714s6nggsw"]